# Keep Ubuntu from auto starting applications at boot

Tags: kubuntu, startup

Is there a best way to  keep this from happening, maybe from the command line. I am running the KDE descktop.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the app that you started. Sometimes an app has its own setting that says "Start every boot". It would help to know which app it is, as every app works differently with the system.